# Blit from multisample textures to non multisample

Tags: opengl, textures, fbo, blit, multisampling

I've one MS FBO with 3 attached MS textures and nonMS FBO also with 3 attacheed nonMS textures. Is there a way how to blit that? If i blit FBO's entirely, MS FBO combines it in a one texture, and that's not working. How to make that separately?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Framebuffer blitting](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer#Blitting) can only read from a single color attachment (specified by `glReadBuffer`) at one time. It can blit to multiple output attachments (specified by `glDrawBuffers`), but that's just copying the same rectangle to multiple destinations.

If you want to read from each image and write to the corresponding image, you need to use 3 separate blitting function calls.

Comment: Thank you! That works!
  
'glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, AAFBO);
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, FBO);
glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, 0, 0, screenWidth,screenHeight, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST); and etc.